# Skmap internal Error

Tags: android, navigation, skmaps

On Zooming In and Out of the Skmap in android application, I get this error in logcat. How do I resolve this issue?

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x2ef43a49 in tid 22639 (GLThread 1245)